# Why does this address bus access only 1MB?

Tags: microprocessors

Hello I am studying microprocessor course  and there is something called the address bus  which is 20 bit wide and I didn't why there is a limit why and how did we come up with "it can address 1MB " I know it is 2^20 but why do we do that?

Comment: I think the answer to the question you're trying to put is cost. But expressing your question in a couple of sentences that don't run on is needed to get a proper answer.

Comment: Are you wondering why there is a limit, or why there's this particular limit, or why a 20-bit bus is limited to 1 MB?

Comment: You're studying a very old processor. Right now the address bus is physically 48 bits wide. Back in those days they simply did not have the transistor small enough to have a bigger address bus.

Comment: sorry i've always struggled with explaining any thing to people but i guess what i want to understand is why the address bus is what Determines the size of the memory

Answer (score 1):

The constraint is due to the size and cost of the physical memory chip itself.  I will try to give a layman's explanation.

Each bit in the address bus is physically implemented as a pin or wire that protrudes from the bottom of the chip.  Since chips are typically pretty small, the number of pins you can fit on the chip is limited, and you can only put the pins so close together (they need to be soldered to the motherboard, which is not something that is done on a microscopic scale).  A memory chip has to have one pin for each bit in the address bus and another pin for each bit in the data bus, so if your chip has a 64-bit address space and a 32-bit data bus then that's already 96 pins you have to cram onto the chip (plus additional pins for ground, clock, etc.)

The way you get data out of a memory chip is to apply voltage to the address bus pins in a pattern that specifies the address you wish to access.  You then reset the voltage on a control pin to indicate that you are finished setting up the address bus.  The chip, through the magic of transistors and other sorts of micro/logical voltage gates, then sets the voltage of the pins in the data bus to a pattern which represents data at that address.  The pattern in the data bus can be interpreted as a binary number.

In binary systems, there are only two voltage states possible for each pin, so if you have 20 pins in the address bus you can only provide 2^20 unique permutations of voltages and therefore you can only ask for 2^20 = 1048576 possible addresses.